# Ad Width larger than Screen Width in Mediation

Tags: android

I have used Millineal media, jumtap ads through Ad mob mediation in android(adSize constant used: IAB_Banner). I have used absolute layout and set LayoutParams to attach the Adview. I gave the width parameter in layoutparams as the screen width.

But the displayed ad width is greater than screen width.(note: if my layout width is smaller than ad width then no ads wont be shown. Its given in admob medition).

I also tried Relative layout with adparams width as "MatchParent". But no difference with that. (Inmobi,admob ads displayed correctly in both of the layout, don't know whether the problem is with the  Millineal media/jumptap ).
    thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

First: Don't use absolute layout any more because it's deprecated.

The adsize is probably to big for a phone. I don't know if you want it to show on a tablet but the standard Banner size for phones is "Banner" instead of "IAB_Banner".
Have a look at your Logcat it will mostly show you what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks.. I found the reason. I mistaken the ad size as pixels(its in dip). Because the ads show properly in all mdpi devices and streched in other density device..